# How to delete item from collection property of entity framework TPH subtype?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a `EquityWatchList : WatchList` class as below:

```
public class EquityWatchList : WatchList
{
    public virtual ICollection<Stock> Stocks { get; set; }

    public EquityWatchList()
    {
        this.Stocks = new List<Stock>();
    }
}
```

This maps through to the database using TPH with a discriminator field for the base class properties. It successfully `Adds` stocks to the `WatchListEquities` table via the following mapping:

```
public class EquityWatchListMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EquityWatchList>
{
    public EquityWatchListMap()
        : base()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.ID);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.UserID)
            .HasMaxLength(128);

        this.Ignore(t => t.State);
        this.Ignore(t => t.UsePropertyNotifications);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("WatchList");
        this.Property(t => t.ID).HasColumnName("ID");
        this.Property(t => t.Name).HasColumnName("Name");
        this.Property(t => t.UserID).HasColumnName("UserID");
        this.Property(t => t.Type).HasColumnName("Type");

        // Relationships
        this.HasMany(t => t.Stocks)
            .WithMany(t => t.EquityWatchLists)
            .Map(m =>
             {
                 m.ToTable("WatchListEquities");
                 m.MapLeftKey("WatchListId");
                 m.MapRightKey("StockId");
             });
    }
}
```

This all happens using a disconnected context. My problem is when I try to delete any stocks from the `WatchList` as upon saving they are never deleted.

I've read this article [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/delete-many-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx) which says you basically have to requery the db for how things were, then compare that to what is in memory, delete from how things were and then re-save. This sounds so wrong but even if it sounded ok I can't seem to do it because there is no `DbSet<EquityWatchList>` from which to delete stocks, there is only the base `DbSet<WatchList>`?

Is this basically impossible?

Comment: could you add the code that shows how you delete entities and how you save it to the store ? perhaps you could check the state of your entities : context.Entry(myentity).State (== EntityState.Modified or Added or Unmodified...)

Comment: I just call Remove on the ICollection of Stocks in reverse of calling Add. There is no where for me to check the state of entity as a member of  the collection, if i did as you suggest I'd just get the state of the Stock entity itself, not the state of that Stock entity as a member of a collection of Stocks for a given WatchList. EF seems to hide this stuff.